# How to import a project into eclispe BY CODE (without GUI)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, headless

I just encountered a problem of my headless plugin-in.

I need to refer some existing Java project for JDT analysis, except that I must import (not necessarily copy) them to the local workspace before the `IWorkspaceRoot.getProject()` can recognize them.

The project will be either a folder or a .zip file. Anyone got some ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loadProjectDescription` in `IWorkspace`. Something along these lines:

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
final IProjectDescription description = theWorkspace.loadProjectDescription(path);
final IProject project = workspace.getRoot().getProject(description.getName());
```